# Using psycopg2 directly on Google AppEngine

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

When using Google Appengine Flexible + Python, how to use Psycopg2 directly (without SQLAlchemy) to access a CloudSQL PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello `myselfhimself`,

Here is a solution:

1. in your `app.yaml`, add an environment variable, imitating [Google Appengine Flexible Python CloudSQL documentation's](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres) SQLAlchemy's URI but without the `psycopg2+` prefix:

> ```
> env_variables:
>     PSYCOPG2_POSTGRESQL_URI: postgresql://user:password@/databasename?host=/cloudsql/project-name:region:database-instance-name
> ```

2. in any python file to be deployed and run, pass that environment variable to `psycopg2`'s `connect` statement directly. This leverages `psycopg2.connect`'s ability to pass the URI directly to the `psql` client library (this might not work with older PostgreSQL versions..).

> ```
> import os
> import psycopg2
> conn = psycopg2.connect(os.environ['PSYCOPG2_POSTGRESQL_URI'])
> ```

3. when working locally with the google cloud proxy tool, make sure you set the URI environment variable first, if your local server is not aware of `app.yaml`:

> ```
> export PSYCOPG2_POSTGRESQL_URI="postgresql://user:password@/databasename?host=/cloudsql/project-name:region:database-instance-name"
> ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project-name:region:database-instance-name=tcp:5432
> #somewhat later:
> python myserver.py
> ```

I hope it will work for your too : )